# How to bind to singleton object instance

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

So i have next class, called NavigationController it will control all actions related to navigation - menus, pages, popups etc.:

```
public class NavigationController: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region ~~~ Fields ~~~

    private NavigationController instance;

    private bool isNavigationMenuOpen;

    #endregion
    #region ~~~ Constructors ~~~

    private NavigationController()
    {

    }

    #endregion
    #region ~~~ Events ~~~

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
    #region ~~~ Properties ~~~

    public NavigationController Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(instance==null)
            {
                instance = new NavigationController();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public bool IsNavigationMenuOpen
    {
        get
        {
            return isNavigationMenuOpen;
        }

        set
        {
            if (isNavigationMenuOpen != value)
            {
                isNavigationMenuOpen = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsNavigationMenuOpen"));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region ~~~ Methods ~~~

    public void OpenNavigationMenu()
    {
        this.IsNavigationMenuOpen = true;
    }

    public void CloseNavigationMenu()
    {
        this.IsNavigationMenuOpen = false;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

On my MainPage.xaml i have a Menu, that has a property IsPaneOpen and it is binded this way:

```
IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsNavigationMenuOpen, Source={StaticResource NavigationController}}"
```

So i'm adding NavigationController as a resource:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <controllers:NavigationController x:Key="NavigationController"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

And get error:

> XAML NavigationController type cannot be constructed. In order to be
>   constructed in XAML, a type cannot be abstract, interface, nested,
>   generic or a struct, and must have a public default constructor

But the code3 above is not binding to an instance, it will create new object. **How can i bind to an instance?**

So as suggested here, i changed to this:

```
private static NavigationController instance;


public static NavigationController Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(instance==null)
            {
                instance = new NavigationController();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
```

And the path:

```
<ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsChecked="{Binding Path=NavigationController.Instance.IsNavigationMenuOpen, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource NavigationController}}">
        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/menu-icon.png"></Image>
    </ToggleButton>
```

And made constructor public

And still when i toggle the button in one control, the other control doesn't react. **What is the problem?** I think two instances were created for each control...

Comment: *"and must have a public default constructor"* Seems like the error is pretty clear... To bind to the instance, set the binding path to that, like `NavigationController.Instance`.

Comment: added an edit please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference that Instance property in your XAML. So, when binding, you'll need to dot into it (and remove the static from Instance).

> Instance.IsNavigationMenuOpen

However, as indicated in the other answer, consider a new design. Perhaps build a new type exposing a singleton instance that all other controller types can reference. That way, at least, it untangles it a bit.

Comment: Yea, you are correct, if i use Path=Instance.IsNavigationMenuOpen instead of Path=NavigationController.Instance.IsNavigationMenuOpen all works. Thanks

Comment: On another note, you should probably revisit your getter of that Instance and ensure only one thread can set it. Look into double-check locking (which works great for C#) or the built in Lazy<T> class. Or, more simply, just move it to a static constructor, since I'm guessing you'll always want it created.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly implement the Singleton pattern the Instance property should be static

Comment: Further reading your question, it seems you can't implement the Singleton pattern here. For a correct implementation of this pattern you need the constructor to be private, but it seems WPF does not allow it. Is there a reason why your class must be a Singleton?

Comment: Many controls will use this to communicate to each-ther. For example the ToggleButton in the header will have Two Way binding, so i click the toggle button, the Left menu starts the animation to show up. When i select some page - the Header will change the title etc.